# How to implement a Java light weight dependency analizer that generates a simple text raw listing?

Tags: java, diagram, loose-coupling

The output should show something simple like this (or anything else that could be still simple):

```
A depends on B, C and D  
B depends on E and F  
F depends on A (warning: coupling problem!)
```

The coupling detection warn isnt even necessary initially.

I thought it should load all the compiled classes and show their inter dependencies? or could be done in some other way?

It is intended to be just something we could further parse/filter to determine if our project has good low coupling.

Also, considering classes are loaded on demand, therefore we would have to run some kind of JUnit that tests all application flows, what would surely not be a problem at all.

**Why not use some already available application?**
1) I cant use IntelijIdea (too heavy).
2) I have tried some others that are Eclipse plugins or external application but some didnt work, or the usage and shown results were quite confusing or even incomplete!
3) other options are not free

Comment: That would be a `take my money` tool.

Comment: I guess a custom class loader could do the trick?

Comment: any reason for the closing vote? something I could edit?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Asking for a tool /libraries is fully off topic. Beyond that it is unclear what exactly you expect from us.

Comment: @OldProgrammer sure thx! forgot, fixing!

Comment: @OldProgrammer done, btw the ending is just to prevent comments about why I dont use something else as I tried a lot of things already (and I was looking for something free and light weight).

Comment: @alayor found an alternative already implemented, see [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/40548/20687), I think it is also possible with [StarUML and WhiteStarUML](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/software-to-generate-class-diagram-from-java-source-not-dependent-on-eclipse?rq=1) but both may require a reverse engineering java extension, and I havent tried them yet.